# Mapping two list without looping

Tags: python

I have two lists of equal length. The first list `l1` contains data.

```
l1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, ... , 23]
```

The second list `l2` contains the category the data in `l1` belongs to:

```
l2 = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, ... , 3]
```

How can I partition the first list based on the positions defined by numbers such as `1, 2, 3, 4` in the second list, using a *list comprehension* or *lambda function*. For example, `2, 3, 7` from the first list belongs to the same partition as they have corresponding values in the second list.

The number of partitions is known at the beginning.

Comment: What do you mean by partition? What is the expected output datastructure? A list? A dict?

Comment: @timgeb anything works. The goal is to find centroid on [this algorithm](http://stanford.edu/~cpiech/cs221/handouts/kmeans.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
>>> l1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 23] 
>>> l2 = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3]

>>> d = {}
>>> for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
...     d.setdefault(j, []).append(i)
... 
>>> 
>>> d
{1: [2, 3, 7], 2: [5], 3: [8, 23], 4: [10]}
```

Comment: What about the *"(...) without looping"* part?

Answer (score 8):

If a `dict` is fine, I suggest using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for number, category in zip(l1, l2):
...     d[category].append(number)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [2, 3, 7], 2: [5], 3: [8, 23], 4: [10]})
```

Consider using [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) for memory efficiency if you are using Python 2.

This is basically the same solution as Kasramvd's, but I think the `defaultdict` makes it a little easier to read.

Comment: can it be optimized for performance? My data set is really really big.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha yes, use `itertools.izip` for big lists.

Answer (score 2):

This will give a list of partitions using list comprehension :

```
>>> l1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 23] 
>>> l2 = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3]
>>> [[value for i, value in enumerate(l1) if j == l2[i]] for j in set(l2)]
[[2, 3, 7], [5], [8, 23], [10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A nested list comprehension :

`[ [ l1[j] for j in range(len(l1)) if l2[j] == i ] for i in range(1, max(l2)+1 )]`

Answer (score 1):

If it is reasonable to have your data stored in `numpy`'s *ndarrays* you can use extended indexing

```
{i:l1[l2==i] for i in set(l2)}
```

to construct a dictionary of *ndarrays* indexed by category code.

There is an overhead associated with `l2==i` (i.e., building a new Boolean array for each category) that grows with the number of categories, so that you may want to check which alternative, either `numpy` or `defaultdict`, is faster with your data.

I tested with `n=200000`, `nc=20` and `numpy` was faster than `defaultdict` + `izip` (124 vs 165 ms) but with `nc=10000` `numpy` was (much) slower (11300 vs 251 ms)

Answer (score 1):

Using some `itertools` and `operator` goodies and a sort you can do this in a one liner:

```
>>> l1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 23] 
>>> l2 = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3]
>>> itertools.groupby(sorted(zip(l2, l1)), operator.itemgetter(0))
```

The result of this is a `itertools.groupby` object that can be iterated over:

```
>>> for g, li in itertools.groupby(sorted(zip(l2, l1)), operator.itemgetter(0)):
>>>     print(g, list(map(operator.itemgetter(1), li)))

1 [2, 3, 7]
2 [5]
3 [8, 23]
4 [10]
```

Comment: With `n=200000` and `nc=20` I measured a best timing of 1960 ms. Because most of the time is spent in `sorted` (just a reasonable guess) it happens that, for larger `nc` you have marginally better timings, e.g., `nc=200` -> 1880 ms, `nc=2000` -> 1820 ms and `nc=10000` -> 1680 ms. I wonder if the underlying sorting algorithm behaves better when there is more difference in data to be sorted...

Answer (score 1):

This is not a list comprehension but a dictionary comprehension. It resembles @cromod's solution but preserves the "categories" from `l2`:

```
{k:[val for i, val in enumerate(l1) if k == l2[i]] for k in set(l2)}
```

Output:

```
>>> l1
[2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 23]
>>> l2
[1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3]
>>> {k:[val for i, val in enumerate(l1) if k == l2[i]] for k in set(l2)}
{1: [2, 3, 7], 2: [5], 3: [8, 23], 4: [10]}
>>>
```